# Why are rows affected after executing and committing the same transaction more than once?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I have a transaction filled with updates that goes like:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION updateCompanyNames;

UPDATE Companies 
SET name = 'abc Inc.' 
WHERE name = 'abc inc';
...
COMMIT TRANSACTION updateCompanyNames
```

I committed the transaction, but when I re-executed it, some rows were not affected, as one would expect, but others keep having the same number of rows affected, no matter how many times I execute the transaction and commit.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using a case-insensitive collation so the same rows will qualify every time the query runs. The row count following the `UPDATE` reflects the number of qualifying rows even if the current column value has not changed. However, SQL Server doesn't actually update unchanged row(s) as an optimization.

Use a `COLLATE` clause can be used to coerce case case sensitive comparison. Specify a case-sensitive version of the current column collation. For example, with a `Latin1_General_CI_AS` column collation, specify `Latin1_General_CS_AS`:

```
UPDATE Companies 
SET name = 'abc Inc.' 
WHERE 
    name = 'abc inc' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

The downside with the above query is the expression is not sargable so a scan will be required even if an index exists on the column. Performance and concurrency can be improved by including the case-insensitive criteria too. The case-insensitive predicate will facilitate an index seek to locate the row(s) that may need to be updated while the case-sensitive predicate limits the rows to those that differ by case.

```
UPDATE Companies 
SET name = 'abc Inc.' 
WHERE 
    name = 'abc inc'
    AND name = 'abc inc' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

Comment: Is this how to fix it? 
`SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('collation')`
and then add it to
`UPDATE..SET...WHERE foo COLLATE (collation) = 'abc inc'` ?

Comment: @CharlesLeblanc, you could specify `WHERE foo  = 'abc inc' COLLATE (collation)`, where collation is the case-sensitive version of your column collation.  Be aware this may result in a full scan even if the column is indexed.

Comment: What are the implications of a full scan?

Comment: @CharlesLeblanc, I added that to my answer along with a query to avoid the scan.